# UIScrollView behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView configured like this :

```
canCancelContentTouches:YES    
delaysContentTouches:NO
```

Inside the UIScrollView, I have a few UIButtons (think thumbnails). If I click a button, the touch is detected and if I then start scrolling, the touch is cancelled on the UIButton as expected.

The issue I'm encountering is if I give the UIScrollView a good swing, and I stop the scrolling by simply touching the UIScrollView, once I touch a UIButton it will receive the touchesCancelled after approximately 1 second of holding the button, until I re-scroll the UIScrollView

The problem seems to come from the UIScrollView still thinking that it is getting dragged (which is false because i haven't moved yet on my last touch).

Strangely, if I disable bouncing via `[UIScrollView setBounces:false]` the issue is not there anymore. But I obviously lose the bounce, which is problematic.

I have tried a bunch of thing like disabling/re-enabling the scrollview, its gesture recognizer. I'm running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here when uibutton receives  touch began you can set uiscrollview contentsize equal to uiscrollview superview size.

When uibutton receives touch end you can set uiscrollview contentsize back to what it was before.

By setting uiscrollview contentsize equal to uiscrollview superview size it will not allow uiscrollview content to move.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the user should be able to scroll at all time. I need a way to tell the UIScrollView that after I'm done touching it, it stops thinking that it is still being dragged on my next touch

Comment: When uibutton receives touch end when you set uiscrollview contentsize back to what it was before then UIScrollview will be scrollable. you have to subclass your UIButton and add - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event here you set the scrollview contentsize equal to superview size and - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event here you set scrollview contentsize back to what it was before